# mongodb-org conflicts with mongodb-10gen-server

Tags: mongodb

I'm running into problems installing Mongo using yum on CentOS. I've followed [these instructions](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/tutorial/install-mongodb-on-red-hat-centos-or-fedora-linux/) but am getting errors when installed the `mongodb-org` package:

```
$ sudo yum install mongodb-org
Loaded plugins: fastestmirror, presto
Loading mirror speeds from cached hostfile
 * base: mirrors.cmich.edu
 * extras: mirror.es.its.nyu.edu
 * updates: mirror.kentdigital.net
Setting up Install Process
Resolving Dependencies
--> Running transaction check
---> Package mongodb-org.x86_64 0:2.6.1-0.1.rc0 will be installed
--> Processing Dependency: mongodb-org-server = 2.6.1 for package: mongodb-org-2.6.1-0.1.rc0.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: mongodb-org-shell = 2.6.1 for package: mongodb-org-2.6.1-0.1.rc0.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: mongodb-org-mongos = 2.6.1 for package: mongodb-org-2.6.1-0.1.rc0.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: mongodb-org-tools = 2.6.1 for package: mongodb-org-2.6.1-0.1.rc0.x86_64
--> Running transaction check
---> Package mongodb-org-mongos.x86_64 0:2.6.1-0.1.rc0 will be installed
---> Package mongodb-org-server.x86_64 0:2.6.1-0.1.rc0 will be installed
---> Package mongodb-org-shell.x86_64 0:2.6.1-0.1.rc0 will be installed
---> Package mongodb-org-tools.x86_64 0:2.6.1-0.1.rc0 will be installed
--> Processing Conflict: mongodb-org-2.6.1-0.1.rc0.x86_64 conflicts mongo-10gen-server
--> Finished Dependency Resolution
Error: mongodb-org conflicts with mongodb-org-server
 You could try using --skip-broken to work around the problem
 You could try running: rpm -Va --nofiles --nodigest
```

It seems like the mongodb package is conflicting with itself.  Does anybody have an idea what's going on here?  I can also confirm that there are no other mongo packages currently installed on the machine.

Comment: Try to delete old mongo with `sudo yum remove mongo-10gen*` and then try to install your new one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just ran into the same problem. Ernie Hershey from MongoDB helped me resolve it by answering my post in the MongoDB user group:

https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/mongodb-user/5xRQW7ER4hE

You basically need to run `yum makecache` before running `yum install mongodb-org` because of  a bug in how MongoDB RC packages are generated. That solved the problem for me.

Comment: Yup looks like that helped; either that or they just fixed the bug.  The mongo-10gen packages for installing version 2.4 are available again too.