# MongoDB 2.6 Update Error on CentOS using yum

Tags: linux, mongodb, centos, upgrade, yum

I'm trying to update MongoDB 2.4 to 2.6 on my 64-bit CentOS machine. I have removed the old 10gen repository package and created the /etc/yum.repos.d/mongodb.repo file with the new configuration as explained [here](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/tutorial/install-mongodb-on-red-hat-centos-or-fedora-linux/).

However, when I run `sudo yum install mongodb-org`, I get the following error:

**Error: mongodb-org conflicts with mongodb-org-server**

This is the output in the shell:

```
Setting up Install Process
Resolving Dependencies
--> Running transaction check
---> Package mongodb-org.x86_64 0:2.6.1-0.1.rc0 will be installed
--> Processing Dependency: mongodb-org-server = 2.6.1 for package: mongodb-org-2.6.1-0.1.rc0.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: mongodb-org-shell = 2.6.1 for package: mongodb-org-2.6.1-0.1.rc0.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: mongodb-org-mongos = 2.6.1 for package: mongodb-org-2.6.1-0.1.rc0.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: mongodb-org-tools = 2.6.1 for package: mongodb-org-2.6.1-0.1.rc0.x86_64
--> Running transaction check
---> Package mongodb-org-mongos.x86_64 0:2.6.1-0.1.rc0 will be installed
---> Package mongodb-org-server.x86_64 0:2.6.1-0.1.rc0 will be installed
---> Package mongodb-org-shell.x86_64 0:2.6.1-0.1.rc0 will be installed
---> Package mongodb-org-tools.x86_64 0:2.6.1-0.1.rc0 will be installed
--> Processing Conflict: mongodb-org-2.6.1-0.1.rc0.x86_64 conflicts mongo-10gen-server
--> Finished Dependency Resolution
Error: mongodb-org conflicts with mongodb-org-server
 You could try using --skip-broken to work around the problem
 You could try running: rpm -Va --nofiles --nodigest
```

Has anyone else encountered anything similar? What is the best course of action here? Should I try using the `--skip-broken` option? I did a fresh installation in a new box a couple of days ago and did not encounter any problems.

Thanks for your help with this.

Comment: Yes, this guy has the same problem: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23231362/mongodb-org-conflicts-with-mongodb-10gen-server

Comment: have you tried to remove old mongo? Try this and tell what happend `sudo yum remove mongo-10gen*`. If it does the job, I will post this as an answer.

Comment: @SalvadorDali, yes indeed. It looks like something's gone wrong today. They have recently released MongoDB 2.6.1-rc0. Perhaps it is related to that.

Comment: Yes I have. I tried that, but it did not work.

Comment: Than sorry, no idea what can be wrong. Strangely my preproduction server was upgraded to RC0, which is not really good. I have not asked for this... Hope you will fix your problem.

Comment: Yes, it does not make sense. I have made a post in the MongoDB User Group to see what could be going wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

During the release of version 2.6.1-rc0, packages were accidentally published into the MongoDB yum and apt repositories such that new and upgrade requests would install the release candidate 2.6.1-rc0 instead of 2.6.0 (stable release).

Users expecting to install, upgrade to, or retain version 2.6.0 may have inadvertently installed version 2.6.1-rc0, which is a release candidate and not recommended for production use. However, we do not expect that accidentally updating to 2.6.1-rc0 will adversely affect your data or operations.

The packages were incorrectly published on April 22, 5:30pm EDT. The issue was resolved on April 23, 11:30AM EDT. Users who attempted to install or upgrade to version 2.6.0 during this time were affected by this issue.

More information for this issue can be found here: https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/SERVER-13691

Answer (score 1):

My best guess is that the yum build was broken when they updated to version 2.6.1-0.1.rc0.

For a temporary fix you could:

Try the unstable version, which is currently 2.5.5

```
yum install mongodb-org-unstable
```

or the regular mongodb package that comes with OS

```
yum install -y mongodb mongodb-server
```

Comment: Yes, that would be a temporary fix. Unfortunately that won't work for me because this is happening on one of my production replica set members. I agree that the yum build must be broken. I'm trying to get in touch with someone at MongoDB so that they can have a look at it.

Comment: Thanks, this works for me, run "yum install -y mongodb mongodb-server" firsst, and run  "yum install mongodb-org" next for lastest mongodb.

Answer (score 1):

Actually I had the same problem, the process that worked for me was:

1. Stop all mongo processes

   ```
   service mongoInstance stop
   ```
2. Remove mongodb

   ```
   yum remove -y mongodb
   ```
3. If not removed yet

   ```
   rpm -e --noscripts mongodb-server
   ```

After that you may install mongodb-org and re-enable your processes.

Answer (score 0):

Ernie Hershey from MongoDB just answered my post on the MongoDB user group:

https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/mongodb-user/5xRQW7ER4hE

Basically, there is a bug in how MongoDB RC packages are generated. So you need to run `yum makecache` before running `yum install mongodb-org`. That should fix the problem.